# How does handle attachment work in Morse Theory

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading R.E.Gompf and A.I. Stipsicz, **4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus**. I can't understand the 2nd-paragraph of p.101, where they explain framings on the attaching sphere. In particular I cannot understand the sentence "By composing $\varphi$ with a self-diffeomorphism of the second factor of $D^{k}\times D^{n-k}$, we can arrange for [an element of $GL(n-k)$] to be the identity at a preassigned basepoint in $S^{k-1}$."
I can't understand why there is such a diffeomorphism. Please explain to me how to solve my problem.

In addition to this,I don't exactly know the definition of "framing." In my understanding this, it is an identification of a normal bundle with the trivial bundle.Is this correct?

Comment: You should say what $D^k$ means.  Is it the $k$-dimensional disk?  As per "framing", it usually means a choice of global sections that trivialize the bundle under consideration (probably the tangent bundle).

Comment: I think in this case, a "framing" is probably an embedding of a tubular neighborhood of the thing being surgured (in this case, probably a $k$-disk or a $(k-1)$-sphere).

Comment: I editted the question a bit. 失礼しました。

Answer (score 10):

A handle attachment is the process of gluing a copy of $D^k\times D^{n-k}$ to $\partial X$. A (normal) framing gives a recipe for performing such a gluing, by specifying (up to ambient isotopy) a collar of $\partial D^{k}\times \{0\}$ in $X$. Gompf-Stipsicz express this data as:

> 1. An embedding $\varphi_0\colon\, S^{k-1}\to\partial X$ with trivial normal bundle.
> 2. An identification of the normal bundle $\nu\varphi_0(S^{k-1})$ with $S^{k-1}\times \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$.

The claim in the paragraph which confuses you is that the set of framings is a $\pi_{k-1}(O(n-k))$ [torsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsor). That means that it's just like the *group* $\pi_{k-1}(O(n-k))$, except it doesn't have a natural choice of *basepoint*. So identifying a framing with an element of $\pi_{k-1}(O(n-k))$ isn't meaningful in general, but you can identify a *difference* between framings with an element of $\pi_{k-1}(O(n-k))$. So this is an archetypical example of a torsor. John Baez wrote an outstanding exposition of torsors, which I strongly recommend: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html

So arbitrarily *choose* a framing $f_0$ to be the `basepoint'. The goal is now to identify $f\circ f_0^{-1}$ with an element of $\pi_{k-1}(O(n-k))$. A-priori, at any point in $S^{k-1}$, the map $f\circ f_0^{-1}$ is an invertible linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ to itself, thus an element of $GL(n-k)$. The map $f\circ f_0^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, so the element of $GL(n-k)$ varies smoothly as we smoothly change the point in $S^{k-1}$.

Now to the sentence which is confusing you. At preassigned basepoint $p\in S^{k-1}$, map $f\circ f_0^{-1}$ takes as its value some matrix, which we'll call $M$. The group $GL(n-k)$ has two connected components- matrices with positive determinant, and matrices with negative determinant. So, using a bump function, you can construct a diffeomorphism of the second factor of $D^k\times D^{n-k}$ which equals multiplication by $M^{-1}$ in a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, and equals $\pm \mathrm{id}$ outside the closure of a larger neighbourhood $V\supset U$ of $p$ (depending on whether the determinant of $M$ was positive or negative). After composing with such a diffeomorphism, you're left with a map of $S^{k-1}$ into $GL(n-k)$ which equals the identity matrix at $p\in S^{k-1}$. *I.e.* you're left with an element of $\pi_{k-1}(GL(n-k))$.

Finally, Gram-Schmidt the whole story to retract $GL(n-k)$ onto $O(n-k)$. This is standard, but a nice exposition of the details exists in a few places. For example, Thurston explains the mechanics of this deformation retract in **3-Dimensional Geometry and Topology** on page 204.

And you're done! It's actually quite simple and elegant once you work through it, although some nice illustrations would make it even more so.

Comment: I can understand your idea,but you didn't write a definition of "framing."Tell me the definition your using.

Comment: @math_takahiro: The answer above quotes Gompf and Stipsicz's definition of a (normal) framing of the embedding $\varphi_0: S^{k-1} \longrightarrow \partial X$ on page 100: it is a choice of trivialization of the normal bundle, _i.e._ a bundle isomorphism $f: \nu(\varphi_0(S^{k-1})) \longrightarrow \underline{\mathbb{R}}^{n-k}_{S^{k-1}}$, where $\underline{\mathbb{R}}^{n-k}_{S^{k-1}}$ is the trivial rank $n-k$ bundle over $S^{k-1}$. We consider two framings equivalent if they are isotopic as bundle maps, so a framing is really a choice of _isotopy class_ of a trivialization.

Comment: Let $\varphi: V^k \hookrightarrow M^n$ be an embedding. An equivalent definition of a normal framing of $V$ in $M$ is that it is a choice of an isotopy class of sections of the frame bundle of the normal bundle of $V$ in $M$. In other words, it is a choice of (an isotopy class of) $(n-k)$ sections $f = (\psi_1, \dots, \psi_{n-k})$ of the normal bundle $\nu$ of $V$ in $M$ such that $(\psi_1(x), \dots, \psi_{n-k}(x))$ is a basis of the fiber of $\nu$ over $x$ for all $x \in V$.

Comment: With the second definition above, it is clear how you get an element of $\mathrm{GL}(n-k)$ for each point $x \in V$ by comparing a reference framing $f_0$ with an arbitrary framing $f$: you look at the change of basis matrix between the bases of the fiber of $\nu$ over $x$ determined by $f_0$ and $f$.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton:I can understand your explanation.Thank you!

Comment: Sorry,I haven't understood the definition of isotopy of framing sufficiently. Please tell me it.

Comment: @Daniel Moskovich: Small error; number 2 in your box should be an identification with $S^{k-1} \times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ ; the normal bundle has dimension $n-k$.

Comment: @Daniel Moskovich the self diffeomorphism that was crafted to achieve an element of $\pi_{k-1}(GL(n-k),p)$ depends on the pair $(f,f_0)$. Does that matter?

Comment: I want to complement the sentence "A (normal) framing gives a recipe for performing such a gluing, by specifying (up to ambient isotopy) a collar of $\partial D^k\times\{0\}$ in $X$" of this answer by making the recipe explicit, so here it goes:

Comment: There're technically two choices done. First of a diffeo $\Phi: N(S^{k-1})\to \nu(S^{k-1})\subset \partial X$ from the abstract normal bundle of $S^{k-1}$ to a neighborhood (called tubular) of $S^{k-1}$ in $\partial X$. The second is a choice of framing, so say $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_{n-k}:S^{k-1}\to N(S^{k-1})$. The induced embedding $S^{k-1}\times D^{n-k}\to \partial X$ is then $(p, x^1,...,x^{n-k})\mapsto \Phi(x^1\sigma_1(p)+...+x^{n-k}\sigma_{n-k}(p))$.

Comment: $\Phi$ is unique up to isotopy by the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem, so it's usually not mentioned. The isotopy classes of framing are given by $\pi_{k-1}(SO(n-k))$.