# Which manifolds have a circle as their boundary?

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

The boundary of a disk or of a Möbius band is a circle.

Which other manifolds share that property?

Comment: Doesn't the boundary of the Möbius strip have two components?

Comment: @Mercy : No.  Just one.

Comment: Would it just be every surface without a boundary, since you could just puncture it?

Comment: Yes I see, but it seems it isn't really a circle, meaning that it's not contained in a plane.

Comment: @Mercy : It's topologically a circle.  That's what I had in mind.  I.e. it's homeomorphic to the ordinary circle in the plane.

Comment: I wonder if what I've done here is asked a question with a completely trivial answer, when I should have asked a different question with a less trivial answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the compact case, I believe the answer is, as you said in the comments above, any closed surface with a single puncture, *i.e.* a disk removed. I claim that this completely classifies compact surfaces with boundary $S^1$. This is because you can glue a disk to the surface along its boundary to obtain a closed surface, and there is a unique way to do this (see, for example, Example 4.1.4(c) in Gompf and Stipsicz's *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*). So by the classification of surfaces, there should then be a unique surface with boundary $S^1$ corresponding to each closed surface.

Comment: So if there were more than one way to glue the disk back on to the punctured surface, then two different surfaces when punctured would result in the _same_ surface with the circle as its boundary.  And you're saying that does not happen.  So maybe my question was not as trivial as I thought just after I posted it.  Or maybe the proof of this uniqueness claim is still trivial.

Comment: In this case, the different ways to attach a disk ($2$-handle) to a surface with boundary $S^1$ are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of $\pi_1(\mathrm{O}(0)) = 0$. See the following answer regarding the relevant part of Gompf and Stipsicz on this topic: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/131947/24934